# How to correctly subclass and plug into view QAbstractProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt

What do I have to do in order to correctly subclass QAbstractProxyView and make it work with view such as QListView. So far I've did this:

```
class Proxy : public QAbstractProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Proxy(QAbstractItemModel* source_model = 0, QObject *parent = 0);
    QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex & proxyIndex) const;
    QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex & sourceIndex) const;
    virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column,
                              const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
     virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const;
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex&, int = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

signals:

public slots:

};
```

Every functionin this class is implemented in separate `cpp` file. Unfortunately doing in my `Ui` class:

```
Proxy* p = new Proxy;
p->setSourceModel(model_);//model is of class Model
listView->setModel(p);
```

doesn't work; Data from model are not displayed in `listView`.

Comment: What did you try? Did you put some `qDebug` statements to check if functions like `data` or `index` are being called?

Comment: @Laurent yes, I did put qDebug statement and those methods from Proxy are not called. What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

If it is meant to work with QListView, you should make your model inherit from `QAbstractListModel`. You only need to implement three methods: the constructor, `rowCount` and `data`. Also see this post for more information: [How to create a custom model for a QListView in Qt](http://pogopixels.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-model-for-a-qlistview-in-qt/)